# Represent a very small number and very large number in a graphic?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I would like to plot 6 values in a bar chart. One of them is very small. When I use yscale('log') function. The rest value can represent but the smallest can not output in the chart. Is there has any approach to set the y-axis value in the chart?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

height = [-1000, 2, 5, 3, 6, 7]
bars = ('A', 'B', 'C','D', 'E', 'F')
y_pos = np.arange(len(bars))

plt.bar(y_pos, height, color = (0.572549,0.2862,0.0,1))
plt.xlabel('Matrix Dimensions')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.ylabel('Fidelity for Matrices with Sparsity 1')
plt.xticks(y_pos, bars)
plt.ylim(-1000,20)
plt.show()
```

[image: Output]

Comment: use log scale on `y` axis?

Comment: [Broken axis](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/broken_axis.html)?

Comment: can I plot two data with different scales?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is that you are setting the minimum y-value on ylim to -1000 and you are using the yscale as log, you should use the symmetic log scale:

```
plt.yscale('symlog')
```

This means that it will scale logarithmically to both sides of 0.
Implemented on your code it should be:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

height = [-1000, 2, 5, 3, 6, 7]
bars = ('A', 'B', 'C','D', 'E', 'F')
y_pos = np.arange(len(bars))

plt.bar(y_pos, height, color = (0.572549,0.2862,0.0,1))
plt.xlabel('Matrix Dimensions')
plt.yscale('symlog')
plt.ylabel('Fidelity for Matrices with Sparsity 1')
plt.xticks(y_pos, bars)
plt.ylim(-1000,20)
plt.show()
```

This shows the following plot:
[symlogplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4w5k.png)

Comment: By "should" the OP means "could".  symlog should be used with caution because it has an arbitrary parameter that most people don't realize is there, in that there is a linear region around zero.  By default this is plus or minus 1.0, but one should specify this when explaining what this plot does in a report or publication.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the log function, it's not defined for negative numbers. matplotlib cant plot a number that's not defined.

Comment: can I plot two data with different scales?

Comment: @janicewww check out this tutorial: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/plotting-with-two-y-axes.html